# What is the role of TimeDistributed layer in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to grasp what TimeDistributed wrapper does in Keras.

I get that TimeDistributed "applies a layer to every temporal slice of an input."

But I did some experiment and got the results that I cannot understand.

In short, in connection to LSTM layer, TimeDistributed and just Dense layer bear same results.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape = (10, 20), return_sequences = True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
print(model.output_shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape = (10, 20), return_sequences = True))
model.add((Dense(1)))
print(model.output_shape)
```

For both models, I got output shape of **(None, 10, 1)**.

Can anyone explain the difference between TimeDistributed and Dense layer after an RNN layer?

Comment: There currently ssem to be no difference, [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/278) a discussion about it. I think the original intent was to make a distinction between the `Dense` layer flattening the input and then reshaping, hence connecting different time steps and having more parameters, and `TimeDistributed` keeping the time steps separated (hence having less parameters). In your case `Dense` should have had 500 paramters, `TimeDistributed` only 50

Comment: @gionni Nope, it has same number of parameters (both 6). So there is virtually no difference atm?

Comment: Yeah exactly, those are the number of parameters they would have if there was a difference. At the moment there isn't

Answer (score 110, accepted):

In `keras` - while building a sequential model - usually the second dimension (one after sample dimension) - is related to a `time` dimension. This means that if for example, your data is `5-dim` with `(sample, time, width, length, channel)` you could apply a convolutional layer using `TimeDistributed` (which is applicable to `4-dim` with `(sample, width, length, channel)`) along a time dimension (applying the same layer to each time slice) in order to obtain `5-d` output.

The case with `Dense` is that in `keras` from version 2.0 `Dense` is by default applied to only last dimension (e.g. if you apply `Dense(10)` to input with shape `(n, m, o, p)` you'll get output with shape `(n, m, o, 10)`) so in your case `Dense` and `TimeDistributed(Dense)` are equivalent.

Comment: There's an example of using TimeDistributed wrapping the model itself. When this is applied to an `Input` tensor, is there any difference from this compared to just doing a `map` of the model applied to a list that contains each slice of the `Input`?

Answer (score 1):

```py
B = 2 # number of batches
d_model = 8 # embedding dimension
T = 3 # number of timesteps

dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)
inp = np.random.randn(B, T, d_model)

# using TimeDistributed layer
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(T, d_model)) # (B, T, d_model)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(dense_layer)(inputs) # (B, T, 16)
model1 = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

otpt1 = model1(inp)
```

`TimeDistributed` Layer applies the layer wrapped inside it to each timestep
so the input shape to the `dense_layer` wrapped inside is `(B, d_model)`, so after the applying the `dense_layer` with weights of shape `(d_model, 16)` the output is `(B, 16)`, doing this for all time steps we get output of shape `(B, T, 16)`.

```py
# Without using TimeDistributed layer
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(T, d_model)) # (B, T, d_model)
outputs = dense_layer(inputs) # (B, T, 16)
model2 = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

otpt2 = model2(inp)
```

Without using the `TimeDistributed` the input shape to the `dense_layer` is `(B, T, d_model)` so the weights dimension is `(d_model, 16)` which applies to all the batches `B` to give output shape `(B, T, 16)`

```py
np.all(otpt1.numpy() == otpt2.numpy()) # True
```

- `Dense` without `TimeDistributed` computes per`Batch`
- `TimeDistributed` with `Dense` computes per `Timestep`